# How to display text in JFrame using Netbeans? How to clear text in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, label

How can I display text in `JFrame` using Netbeans? And how to clear text in JFrame?

Comment: Note: this has nothing to do with Netbeans. Think of Netbeans as only a tool for editing your sources, not part of the language itself.

Answer (score 2):

to create a label for text:

```
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("your text here");
```

to change the text in the label:

```
label1.setText("your new text here");
```

and finally to clear the label:

```
label1.setText("");
```

and all you have to to is place the label in your layout, or what ever layout system you are using, and then just add it to the JFrame..

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
@Override
public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.drawString("Hello", 0, 0);
}
```

or use jTextField

```
 jTextField1.setText("Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JLabel` to display text, and you can reset by setting its text to "" . check [doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Netbeans GUI builder then there's a good beginner's [tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html). Otherwise, if you're coding manually, there's a good guide to Swing on Oracle's site: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create Jlabel.

```
JLabel l1=new JLabel("Your text");

l1.setText(""); // clear the text
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Properties.Under the Swing Control you will find the JLabel.Drag & DROP it in your JFRAME.

Answer (score 0):

This code works with Netbeans.. create one new Frame and set Text for you in the middle of the Frame..

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("Label For The JFrame");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(107, 107, 107)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(141, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(88, 88, 88)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(187, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /*
     * Set the Nimbus look and feel
     */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /*
     * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
     * default look and feel. For details see
     * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /*
     * Create and display the form
     */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Replace This `jLabel1.setText("Label For The JFrame");` with your customized Label in Code.

and when you want to blank the Label use `jLabel1.setText("");`

Thanks..